# Spring AOP for exception handling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am calling a rest end point like below.
I need to send email if rest call fails i,e if exception occurs in m1 method or response==null.

```
    Foo m1(String s) {
    
        ResponseEntity<Foo> response = restTemplate
          .exchange(fooResourceUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, Foo.class);
        
          response.getbody();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using annotation @AfterThrowing,

AspectJ @AfterThrowing advice is executed after a join point does not complete normally and end up throwing an exception.

In your case, you can create an aspect and implement logic to send email there

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @AfterThrowing ("execution(* com.demo.app.service.impl.demoImpl.*(..))")
    public void doSomethingAfterThrowingAllMethods() throws Throwable { ... }
}
```

Comment: do i need to change my  m1 method too?

Comment: Aspect is global. Just make sure you throw the exception correctly. Aspect will get executed once the exception is thrown.

Comment: well your example is not working...Aspect is not getting execued...see my code here 
https://pastebin.com/3MgCEspK

Comment: you have to specify exception type as well, 

Follow this example, 
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/aop/spring-aop-afterthrowing-advice-type-example/